# how to create a simple neural network using neuroph in java

Tags: java, neural-network

I want to create a neural network using java. I've added my neuroph jar files to my project and have imported all necessary classes. However, I don't understand how to actually declare neural networks or create layers using java code. All the examples I can find use the pre-built GUI which is great but it's not what I'm looking for.

Could someone maybe provide me with a tutorial or a site that would walk me through the different things I can do using neuroph?

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this in Neuroph 2.8:

```
NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = new Perceptron(2, 1);
DataSet trainingSet = new DataSet(2, 1);
trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{0, 0}, new double[]{0}));
trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{0, 1}, new double[]{1}));
trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{1, 0}, new double[]{1}));
trainingSet.addRow(new DataSetRow(new double[]{1, 1}, new double[]{1}));
neuralNetwork.learn(trainingSet);
neuralNetwork.save("/tmp/or_perceptron.nnet");
```

Also see [the API docs](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the import statements?